# UPSERT in parquet Pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, etl, parquet

I have parquet files in s3 with the following partitions: 
year / month / date / some_id
Using Spark (PySpark), each day I would like to kind of UPSERT the last **14 days** - I would like to replace the existing data in s3 (one parquet file for each partition), but not to delete the days that are before 14 days.. 
I tried two save modes: 
*append* - wasn't good because it just adds another file. 
*overwrite* - is deleting the past data and data for other partitions.

Is there any way or best practice to overcome that? should I read all the data from s3 in each run, and write it back again? maybe renaming the files so that *append* will replace the current file in s3?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do something similar. In my case I do an ETL and append one day of data to a **parquet** file:

The key is to work with the data you want to write (in my case the actual date), make sure to partition by the `date` column and overwrite all data for the **current date**.

This will preserve all old data. As an example:

```py
(
    sdf
    .write
    .format("parquet")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .partitionBy("date")
    .option("replaceWhere", "2020-01-27")
    .save(uri)
)
```

Also you could take a look at [delta.io](https://delta.io/) which is an extension of the **parquet** format that gives some interesting features like **ACID** transactions.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, S3 doesn't have an update operation. Once an object is added to s3 cannot be modified. (either you have to replace another object or append a file)

Anyway to your concern that you've to read all data, you can specify the timeline you want to read, partition pruning helps in reading only the partitions within the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the useful solutions. 
I ended up using some configuration that served my use case - using *overwrite* mode when I write parquet, along with this configuration:

I added this config:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
```

with this configuration spark will only overwrite the partitions for which it has data to be written to. All the other (past) partitions remain intact - see here:

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-dynamic-partition-inserts.html